# HTML code to take user form data save in Excel file on common dropbox account

Tags: javascript, html, excel

What I am trying to do is take data from a user form from a website and save an Excel file in a specific dropbox account upon the end user clicking the submit button.  If this can be done safely and without to much taxation I would prefer that as to opposed to receiving multiple emails each time the form is completed.  Does any one have examples of this, bits and pieces that I have learn from would be greatly appreciated.  My programming experience is in C# and I have not attempted much html or javascript. Thank you for your time and efforts!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google forms can do most of the work for you. having user form data stored as records in a google sheet which is stored on your google drive. here's a link to [create a form](https://docs.google.com/forms/create) on google forms.